# CSV swap values in column

Tags: ruby

My 5th column has various US state names using two letter identifiers(CA, NY, WA... etc)  How can I swap out the values for each?  Say I want all CA to be 1, NY to be 2, WA to be 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
require 'csv'
state_map = { CA: 1,NY: 2,WA: 3 }

converted_states = CSV.generate do |csv|
  CSV.foreach('states.csv') do |line|
    key = line[4].to_sym
    line[4] = state_map[key] if state_map.has_key? key
    csv << line
  end
end

puts converted_states #instead of displaying in this place you can save data etc.
```

In this snippet I suppose that you have embedded hash with mappings like `State: Id`

Comment: The file is a simple CSV file.  I am not sure what you mean by embedding a hash.

Comment: if I properly understand you, you have a csv file with values. but you have to define mappings between state's two letter identifiers and some numeric id. Above I meant you have this mapping as hard-coded hash in code for purpose of simplicity.